# Merge DFs with same column name and different row sizes, filling NAN at repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the purpose of this question I have the following two generated DataFrames:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"model": [f"model{i//2}" for i in range(6)], "label": [f"label_{i}" for i in range(6)], "data": [f"data_{i}" for i in range(6)]})
df1 = df1.set_index("model")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"model": [f"model{i}" for i in range(3)], "info": [f"info_{i}" for i in range(3)], "stuff": [f"stuff_{i}" for i in range(3)]})
df2 = df2.set_index("model")
```

`df1` looks like so:

```
[model]  label   data   
model0  label_0 data_0
model0  label_1 data_1
model1  label_2 data_2
model1  label_3 data_3
model2  label_4 data_4
model2  label_5 data_5
```

and `df2` like so:

```
[model]  info    stuff  
model0  info_0  stuff_0
model1  info_1  stuff_1
model2  info_2  stuff_2
```

Where `[...]` indicates the index of the DataFrame. I am looking to somehow join both of these DataFrames to output the following;

```
[model]  info    stuff  label   data   
model0  info_0  stuff_0 label_0 data_0
model0    NAN     NAN   label_1 data_1
model1  info_1  stuff_1 label_2 data_2
model1    NAN     NAN   label_3 data_3
model2  info_2  stuff_2 label_4 data_4
model2    NAN     NAN   label_5 data_5
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation on the how for the above. I have tried multiple combinations of code with `join`, `concat`, and `merge`, but none result on the above. I know I could write a function to do this, but I was hoping this was manageable via Pandas native `join`, `concat`, `merge` functions.

If anyone more experienced with `pandas` could guide me towards the right direction I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we reset the index so that we can merge both data frames on `model` column. Then you can use `duplicated` method from `pd.Series` to mask duplicates and subsequently fill them with `NaN`:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=False)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=False)
df_new = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer')
df_new = df_new.set_index('model')
is_duplicated = df_new.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=0)
df_new = df_new.where(~is_duplicated, np.nan)
```

The new data frame `df_new` is the wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"model": [f"model{i//2}" for i in range(6)], "label": [f"label_{i}" for i in range(6)], "data": [f"data_{i}" for i in range(6)]})
df1 = df1.set_index("model")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"model": [f"model{i}" for i in range(3)], "info": [f"info_{i}" for i in range(3)], "stuff": [f"stuff_{i}" for i in range(3)]})
df2 = df2.set_index("model")

df1_g = df1.groupby(by='model').first()
print(pd.concat([df1_g, df2], axis=1).append( df1[~df1.isin(df1_g)].dropna(), sort=False ).sort_index() )
```

Prints:

```
          label    data    info    stuff
model                                   
model0  label_0  data_0  info_0  stuff_0
model0  label_1  data_1     NaN      NaN
model1  label_2  data_2  info_1  stuff_1
model1  label_3  data_3     NaN      NaN
model2  label_4  data_4  info_2  stuff_2
model2  label_5  data_5     NaN      NaN
```